# Block interaction temporarily ,during wcf call!

Tags: silverlight

How do I block main navigation on (mainpage.xaml) as in all silverlight navigation application and block page's controls ( i.e whichever page is it in ) during async webservice calls? Any best practices?

Comment: But, why?

MS went to a lot of trouble to build in async communications so that potentially blocking server calls would not degrade client performance.

Comment: so that user doesnot abuse my application , he clicks on one navigation , the page is still loading ( data service is called ) and he click another page , and than he does it again .dont you think we should put a control on the user ?

Answer (score 2):

BusyIndicator from Silverlight Toolkit.

Comment: +1 for Busy Indicator. Just wrap a BusyIndicator around your whole control, before the WS call, set IsBusy = true, when the call returns set IsBusy = false. It's easy and beautiful. You'll love it.

Comment: You can block the whole page with BusyIndicator as well.

Answer (score 1):

Make a Please Wait modal dialog on your mainpage.  Open it before you make a webservice call, close it in the your webservice call response handler.

Comment: i think you are right , but how will i access "Please Wait modal dialog "from my viewmodel ?

secondly do you think it's a good idea to block the page during service calls ? since we still have back and forward browser button in browser(i am using navigation) , user can still abuse my application . what do you say ?